# How to make a the user input a command following a certain form in python?

Tags: python, search, input, command, detect

Sorry for the gory title, I can't work out what this would be called.
Basically, I want to ask the user "What would you like to do?" and have them be able to execute a number of commands. For example, they would say "Search for fox" and the program would do

```
if any(search in i for i in list):
    print(list[search])
else:
    print(search + " not found.")
```

So basically, how can I make the code detect the format "Search for [x]" and assign x to the variable search. Also, if there is a name for it, what would this be called? I think that would help me search for it next time.

Comment: is `Search` the command or is `Search for fox` the command?

Comment: What you are describing is parsing the input to extract commands. In the simplest form, you could just do e.g. `if user_input.lower().startswith("search for"):`. More complex versions might involve regular expressions or other parsing techniques.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `Search for` would be the command.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, that's what I mean, thanks. How would I then extract the bit following "Search for" and assign that to a variable?

Comment: @CharlieDeBeadle for the simple version, start by looking at the various [string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below finds the keyword by removing the command (here search for) from the input given by the user, that way the search query is seperated.

```
def search(search_word):
    # your search function here
    pass

# get input from the user
user_input = raw_input("What would you like to do? ").lower()
# make the code easier to reuse
search_command = "search for"

if len(user_input) > 0:
    if user_input.startswith(search_command):
        # use slices to remove the first part of the input, and then remove all whitepsace
        search_word = user_input[len(search_command):].strip()

        search(search_word)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I ended up doing.